# how to save data after closing view

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

In a view I have a tree viewer. I set data in tree viewer. Now, I close application. Again I run application, Now again I have to set the data from beginning. I want that My data will saved, it will not vanished.

Comment: See also: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_does_a_view_persist_its_state_between_sessions%3F But note, however, that view state should be small and only represent the view's **state**, not its data, i.e. do not store the values loaded from a data store but a serializable descriptor that can be used to re-fetch the data in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse RCP save values to workbench](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371886/eclipse-rcp-save-values-to-workbench)

Answer (score 0):

You can use preferences.Copy your data in preferences, and while loading the tree view again get your data from preferences again.

refer this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html